# Is there a term for the interval [-1.0, 1.0]?

Tags: terminology, rational-numbers, interval-arithmetic

When representing data, it is sometimes appropriate to normalize (typically rational) numbers to the range $$[0.0, 1.0]$$
For variables that have symmetric extremes (min, max) around a meaningful zero, the representation $$[-1.0, 1.0]$$ is more appropriate. While the former range can be described as *normalized* and 1.0 as *unity*, is there a specific term for the interval $[-1.0, 1.0]$?

Comment: Please explain downvotes!

Answer (score 2):

A specific term for this object is the closed unit [ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)) in 1-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: Isn’t a two-dimensional sphere a disc? And isn’t a one-dimensional disc a line? Is Lp notation necessary? Can we say that it is a normed space?

Comment: @noumenal Four questions in your comment. Are they related to this answer?

Comment: @Did A single answer to any of those questions would make it clearer to me why a two-point interval should be defined in three dimensions.

Comment: No. Yes. No. DNE.

Answer (score 0):

I have settled for the expression ***signed*** unit interval, borrowing from both mathematics and computer terminology.